# ASP.NET Trial website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I created a web app and I want the users of the app to use limited functionality free.
Or I might even decide down the road to enable free users to use the app for no more than, say 10 days.

is there a library or framework which helps with such issues ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. One of the simplest, if you are using ASP.NET authentication is to use Roles.  Each user can belong to any number of roles.  You can setup a free role and full user (paid user) role and check on your pages to see what kind of user they are.  Based off of that check you can add, remove, or change functionality how every you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ASP.NET's Membership API for this.  You will need to write your own business logic to handle the 10 days.

An excellent tutorial of the Membership API, along with many refinements such as Email verification of accounts, can be found here:

**Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile**
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx